# How to change composer path on local server

Tags: composer-php, wampserver

i have installed composer at window machine

i want to change that composer path to my local wamp drive 
D:\wamp64\www\my-pro

Please suggest
thanks

Comment: do you want to change the "global vendors library"? This command change: `php composer.phar global config bin-dir --absolute`

Comment: here are more explanations: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global